# Working Example of ObservableArrayList with addOnListChangedCallback?

Tags: java, android, listener, android-databinding

Ok I'm ready to pull my hair out XD.

So I'm trying to watch an ArrayList change and update the recycler view when it changes. Should be simple right?

Well, I have an ObservableArrayList in an Singleton:

```
public ObservableArrayList<MyCustomObject> myList = new ObservableArrayList<>();
```

Then I grab that Singleton from my Activity and try to set up a listener:

```
singleTon.myList.addOnListChangedCallback(new myArrayListListener());
```

With the listener:

```
   private class myArrayListListener extends ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback
    {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ObservableList sender) {
            Log.d("List Change", "onChanged");
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            Log.d("List Change", "onItemRangeChanged");
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            Log.d("List Change", "onItemRangeInsert");
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeMoved(ObservableList sender, int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
            Log.d("List Change", "onItemRangeMoved");
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            Log.d("List Change", "onItemRangeRemoved");
        }
    }
```

And yet I haven't been seeing anything in the console as far as the Logs I have. Thus, can't do the `recycler.notify()` quite yet.

Is this the right way to implement the listener? I've tried it with several combinations with no luck still.

Also,it would be dope if one could provide working code with the ObservableArrayList that would be wonderful as I'd like to not go bald please.

Comment: did you modify the data in the list post observing the list?

Comment: yes I did, I confirmed that the list was not empty either.

Comment: can you share the snippet where you add/remove data to the list?

Comment: Code for deletion mapped to button:
`fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                singleTon.myList.remove(0);

            }
        });`
The addition code I cant really share but I know the objects are added to the array thus the listener should be able to pick up on the change in range.